# How can I get a value of a column to 2 decimal points?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

[image: CODE SYNTAX]

As you can see from the columns, i wanted the output to be 2 decimal place as shown on EndOfYearForecast. Any way around it?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROUND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function

```
SELECT
CONCAT("£",ROUND(SUM(cost),2)) AS EndOfYearForecast,
CONCAT("£",ROUND(SUM(cost/12),2)) AS MonthlyAverage,
CONCAT("£",ROUND(SUM(cost/53),2)) AS WeeklyAverage
FROM yearlyAnalysis;
```

You can also use the [FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function if you want commas in the display

```
SELECT
CONCAT("£",FORMAT(SUM(cost),2)) AS EndOfYearForecast,
CONCAT("£",FORMAT(SUM(cost/12),2)) AS MonthlyAverage,
CONCAT("£",FORMAT(SUM(cost/53),2)) AS WeeklyAverage
FROM yearlyAnalysis;
```

## EXAMPLE

```
mysql> SET @NUM=1234.56789; SELECT ROUND(@NUM,2) RoundNum,FORMAT(@NUM,2) FormatNum;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----------+-----------+
| RoundNum | FormatNum |
+----------+-----------+
|  1234.57 | 1,234.57  |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast as decimal and mentions scale number same as number of decimal places you need in your output.  Details about decimal data type [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql).  Using CAST and CONVERT see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

Sample:

```
DECLARE @MonthlyAverage AS FLOAT=179686.787500

SELECT CAST (@MonthlyAverage AS Decimal (18,2))
```

Result
`179686.79`